# Increasing water supply for an irrigation system

Tags: water, irrigation, lawn

I am in the process of planning to install and irrigation system for our front yard.  I have been following guidance provided on the Rain Bird site.
I have measured the pressure at the faucet, and it is ~63psi.  The flow however seems low at 7.2 gallons be min.  Rain Bird Canada specifies a minimum of 8 gallons per minute.  I have been trying to find the most effective way to increase the flow.  The water supply to the house is 3/4", but it is reduced to 1/2 for about 25 feet to the exterior wall hydrant. the inlet at the wall hydrant is also 1/2 inch.  I thought about increasing the 25 feet of 1/2" to 3/4", but a 3/4" inlet on a exterior wall hydrant does not seem to be widely available which leads me to believe that there should be a way that I can get great than 7.2 gallons per minute.  I am on a city water system.
I would appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you,
Grant

Comment: Terminology question:  What is a "wall hydrant"?  A faucet, sometimes called a hose bib  mounted on an outside wall?  In the US we have something called a yard hydrant, which is a tall (3-5') pipe with a large handle on top leading to the valve which is buried.  There is also a drain that engages when the valve is closed to drain the exposed pipe to avoid freezing damage.    OK, on to business:  1/2" is ridiculously small to supply an irrigation system.  For better help, please give us some more specs IE: number of zones, number of heads per zone, flow rate of each head, etc.

Comment: Also, it's very helpful to "take the tour", you get 100 points just to take it and it really helps interact here.

Comment: Hi George, Good question.  It was new to me as well.  https://www.watts.ca/products/plumbing-flow-control-solutions/shutoff-valves/wall-hydrants/fh    I was just starting to plan the system, and Rain Bird requires the PSI, GPM and size to determine the best number of heads/zones.  I have bought no materials yet.  When the Rain Bird site noted that I needed a minimum of 8 GPM, I figured I better resolve that before I go any further,

Comment: Not knowing more about your plans/needs, most irrigation systems of any but the smallest size take the supply from very close to where the water is supplied.  Here is in the US a double check valve with testing capabilities is required.  I would strongly suggest avoiding any 1/2" lines as a supply for your system. It's just too small.

Comment: @george “hydrant” is an alternate name for “sillcock”. It is a horizontal hydrant. Some also call them “faucets” which is not wrong, but is unspecific.

Answer (score 1):

Ok when your pressure flow is low you start breaking the system into zones, rainbird has easy to program controllers that allow you to add multiple zones so the lack of pressure flow for your system is not a limiting factor in getting your entire front yard watered , it just may take running 2 zone then another and as many as needed so you get proper coverage of the sprinklers , I have had as few as 3 sprinkler heads per zone but able to cover ~1/2 acre on a 6 zone system. You may need to split your system into multiple zones to cover your yard with your existing supply.

Comment: Thank you Ed.  The total size of the area to water is 3,000 square feet, so not large be any means.    Rain Bird requires the PSI, GPM and size to determine the best number of heads/zones.  They will prepare an installation plan based on the dimensions I provide.  Based on your comments, perhaps the flow will work.  Thank you!

Comment: Grant if a comment or answer is helpful upvote or accept it that’s how the site works so others can find similar information.